# Bash/csh: test for end of file (EOF) of stdin

Tags: bash, stdin, eof

I would like to do:

```
if not eof(stdin):
   pass stdin to program
else:
   do nothing
```

I have a feeling that it can be written fairly close to:

```
if test ! --is-eof - ; then
  exec program
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that `program` reads from stdin but crashes if it gets no input. I do not have access to the source for `program` thus `program` cannot be changed. The binary input is bigger than the memory size so putting stdin to a file first is unacceptably slow. Processing all the input line-by-line in bash is unacceptably slow also.

The solution should ideally work under both csh and bash.

Comment: You have to read a stream before you can test for EOF.   Sounds like you have a poorly designed script.

Comment: Well, what is that program which crashes? Wouldn't it be better to try and get it not to crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in both csh and bash and deal nicely with binary input (also \0 as first char):

```
# Set $_FIRST_CHAR_FILE to the name of a temp file.
eval `echo $SHELL | grep -E "/(t)?csh" > /dev/null && echo setenv _FIRST_CHAR_FILE /tmp/$$.first_char_file || echo export _FIRST_CHAR_FILE=/tmp/$$.first_char_file`

dd bs=1 count=1 of=$_FIRST_CHAR_FILE >&/dev/null
test -s "$_FIRST_CHAR_FILE" && ( cat $_FIRST_CHAR_FILE; rm $_FIRST_CHAR_FILE; cat - ) | program
```

Thanks to @glenn-jackman for giving the idea of reading a little bit before passing this and the rest of stdin through `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading a line from stdin first:

```
IFS= read -r line
if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
    # the line is non-empty.
    # add the line back into the stream and pipe it into your program
    { echo "$line"; cat -; } | your_program
fi
```

Comment: Your answer fails if the first line of the input is a blank line.  I suggest `if IFS= read -r line; then …`.  Or, if the input might be an incomplete line (e.g., `echo "The quick brown fox jumps …\c" | OleTange.sh`), do `if IFS= read -r line  ||  [[ -n "$line" ]]; then …`.

Comment: I like the idea. It does impose a limit that there must be a \n before size of memory amount of data, which is suboptimal, but might be an acceptable limit. Also it seems not to work if the first \0 is before the first \n, which is not acceptable as the input is binary data. E.g: printf "abc\0def\nghi\njkl" | if ... . Can we ask `read` to read a number of bytes (incl \0) instead of a full line?

Comment: `read -N 1` seems to help, but fails if the first char is \0.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your script to block in an attempt to look for something to read, you can (at least in bash) use a read with timeout

```
$ ( read -t 0 var ; echo $? )
1

$ echo foo | ( read -t 0 var ; echo $? )
0
```

This however does not guarantee that you have EOF but that there is nothing to read at the moment

Comment: Although you (sort of) mention it, this answer is a race condition in and of itself. If a program is not ready to send input (although it "should be" available), the timeout can happen before a program like `cat` can produce its output. Thus, this answer should be avoided due to nondeterministic race-condition-like timing.

Comment: you're right. In my use cases this race condition is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

What kind of input is your program expects ? 
are you piping the output from one program to the other or is it reading a file ?

If you are using pipe redirection to collect input to ur script then it will proceed executing till the input supply is provided.

if you are trying to read from a file then use "while" or "until" to do the job.

Comment: This should be a comment for the question, not an answer

Comment: @glenn: I disagree.  @M is asking a question about the question only to illuminate the situations in which each of his two answers apply.  …  //  …  I agree that it isn’t a _good_ answer, but it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I post here since this came up when searching and since it helped me *debugging* on **Darwin** (snow leopard) **bash** in `set -x;trap 'test -s /dev/stdin||exit' debug` to find a call that was consuming the inherited input of the parent script.

For the faint-hearted:

```bash
if [[ -s /dev/fd/0 ]]
    then echo 'Not at EOF'
    else echo 'Currently no input to read'
fi
```

#### Test:

```bash
echo $((echo|test -s /dev/stdin)&&! (true|test -s /dev/stdin)&&echo pass||echo fail) ${BASH_VERSINFO[*]}
```

The above test yields the following in my bash versions and systems.

`pass 4 2 45 2 release i386-apple-darwin10.8.0`
  `pass 3 2 48 1 release x86_64-apple-darwin10.0`
**`fail 4 2 37 1 release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`**

Piping to `cat /proc/self/fdinfo/0` on my Debian (wheezy) gives nothing to test for either.

CheerIO or rather cheerEO for Erroneous/Output %)

Comment: Would be wonderful if it worked in general. But alas it does not: /dev/fd/* does not exist on hurd, aix, hpux, qnx, tru64, ultrix. /dev/stdin does not exist on irix, aix, hpux, tru64, ultrix.